# question regarding disintegration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

Let $\gamma$ be a positive measure on $(\mathbb R^2)^n$ and define a measure $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^n proj^i_\#\gamma$ on $\mathbb R^2$. Notice that

$\omega= \int_{p \in(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)^n} \alpha_p \,d\gamma(p)$

(or $ \omega= \frac{1}{n}  \int_{p \in(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)^n} \alpha_p \,d\gamma(p)$?)

where $\alpha_p$ is the measure which is
uniformly distributed on the set $\{(x_1, y_1), \ldots,  (x_n, y_n)\}$ whenever $p=\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^n\in(\mathbb R^2)^n$.

**My question**: how to see that if $\alpha_p^\prime$ is a competitor of $\alpha_p$ for each $p$, and $p\mapsto \alpha_p^\prime$ is measurable, then $\omega^\prime= \int_{p \in(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)^n} \alpha_p ^\prime\,d\gamma(p)$ is a competitor of $\omega$ ?

---

**Definition(competitor)** 
Let $\alpha$ be a measure on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ with finite first moment in
the second variable.
We say that $\alpha'$, a measure on the same space, is a **competitor** of $\alpha$ if $\alpha'$ has the same marginals as
$\alpha
$ and for $(proj^x_\#\alpha)$-a.e. $x\in\mathbb R$,

$\int y \,d\alpha_x(y)=\int y \,d\alpha_x'(y)$,

where $(\alpha_x)_{x\in\mathbb R}$ and $(\alpha'_x)_{x\in\mathbb R}$ are
disintegrations of the measures with respect to $proj^x_\#\alpha$.

---

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does $\mu\le\nu$ mean in your first sentence?

Comment: (I guess in the paper) it means $\mu(E)\leq \nu(E)$ for every measurable set $E$.

Comment: So what's the question? $\mu \le \nu$ if and only if $\nu - \mu$ is a positive measure.

Comment: I must have been stupid. Will modify my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That $\omega$ and $\omega^\prime$ have the same marginals is easy to check. It remains to show

$\int_\mathbb R h(x)\int_\mathbb R y \,d\omega_x(y) \,d\omega_1(x)=\int_\mathbb R h(x)\int_\mathbb R y \,d\omega_x^\prime(y) \,d\omega_1^\prime(x)$

for all bounded measurable function $h$, where $\omega_1=\omega_1^\prime$ are the 1st marginal of these measures. This follows from definition-tracing together with the assumption that $\alpha^\prime$ is a competitor of $\alpha$.